# IS NULL being ignored

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, null

I am trying to run a query in T-SQL to pull back a data set based on a column being null.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
SELECT
    T1.Col1, T1.Col2,
    T1.Col3, T1.Col4
FROM
    table1 AS T1
INNER JOIN 
    table2 AS T2 ON T1.Col2 = T2.Col3
WHERE 
    T2.Col4 IS NULL
```

Problem is, the result includes rows where T2.Col4 are NULL and also not NULL, it's like the WHERE clause doesn't exist.

Any ideas would be greatly

UPDATE - full version of code:

```
SELECT  

     M.ref                      
    ,C.cname                            
    ,CL.clname                          
    ,C.ccity                            
    ,M.productLine                      
    ,M.code                         
    ,CL.date
    ,M.dept
    ,DPT.group
    ,TK2.tkname
    ,TK2.tkdept


FROM DB.dbo.manage AS M

        OUTER JOIN DB.dbo.ClientManageRelationship AS CMR 
        ON CMR.RelatedEntityID = M.EntityID

        OUTER JOIN DB.dbo.Client AS C 
        ON C.EntityID = CMR.EntityID

        INNER  JOIN DB.dbo.ManageCustomerRelationship AS MCR 
        ON MCR.EntityID = M.EntityID

        INNER JOIN DB.dbo.Customer AS CL 
        ON CL.EntityID = MCR.RelatedID

        INNER JOIN DB.dbo.timek AS TK
        ON TK.tki = M.tkid

        LEFT JOIN  (SELECT Group = division, [Department] = newdesc, deptcode FROM DB.csrt.vw_rep_p_l_dept) AS DPT
         ON tkdept  = DPT.dept 

        LEFT JOIN (SELECT Name = TK2.tkfirst + ' ' + TK2.tklast, TK2.tki, TK2.dept, TK2.loc FROM DB.dbo.timek as TK2 WITH(NOLOCK)) AS TK2 
         ON TK2.tki = M.tkid 


    WHERE DPT.Department = 'Casualty'
    AND UPPER (C.ClientName) LIKE '%LIMITED%'
    AND CL.date > '31/12/2014'
    AND CL.Date IS NULL
    AND TK.tkloc = 'loc1' OR TK.tkloc = 'loc2'

ORDER BY M.ref
```

Comment: Are you sure ?  Can add T2.Col4 to your select and post sample data and output (in text tabular format)?

Comment: When you run the query without the where, do you get NULLS?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear. T2Col4 is also being selected so I can see the result. I have taken out the where clause, I am getting NULLS and NOT NULLS back, but I am getting a larger result set without the WHERE clause.  Also, there are more joins than in my example code, I don't know if that makes a difference?

Comment: pls post sample data and output as asked above

Comment: Posted in question above

Comment: pls do not cut data: post some sample input value and the output of your query.  And remember to format them in your question (see introduction fonr newbies in Stack Overflow).  Otherwise it's very difficult to help you.

Comment: @mark have you got the columns too?

Comment: CL.date > '31/12/2014'
    AND CL.Date IS NULL doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've never come across an outer join without a qualification (right,left full) what does it default to?

Comment: @P.Salmon my reading of [the syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql) suggests just saying `table OUTER JOIN table` isn't legal, but I might well be misreading it.

Comment: An outer join without qualification will cause a syntax error as will SELECT Group = division - group is a reserved word.

Comment: as @P.Salmon already indicated, your where clause usage of CL.Date (or is it CL.date - inconsistency is a bad sign) is nonsense. The value in that column cannot both be NULL and > than the specified value. Perhaps you want to include rows if either condition is true - but the db engine does not read minds.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. the CL.Date > '31/12/2014' should be commented out, it was just put in to test the clause when NULL or recent. The code is not running with both statements active simultaneously, I made the mistake when making the code more anonymous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first answer would be because you're using INNER JOIN. This only returns matches between the 2 tables. TRY FULL OUTER JOIN which will return all values regardless of matches and will include NULLS.

If you were looking to return all rows regardless of matches including NULLS from only one of the tables then use RIGHT or LEFT JOIN.

Say i had 2 tables ('Person' and 'Figure'). Not every person may have entered a figure on any one day. But an example may be i want to return all people regardless of whether they entered a figure or not on a certain day.

My initial approach to this would be a LEFT join because i want to return of all the people(left table) regardless of there being any matches in the figure table(right table)

```
    FROM Person P
    LEFT JOIN Figure F
    ON P.ID = F.ID
```

This would produce a result such as

```
       Name     Figure

       Sam       20
       Ben       30
       Matt      NULL
      Simon      NULL
```

Whereas,

An inner join would produce only matching values not including nulls

```
      Name     Figure

       Sam       20
       Ben       30
```

Left join works the same way as right join but in the opposite direction. This is most likely the problem you were facing. But i hope this helped

Comment: Thanks Ryan. This does produce the right result but I don't understand the issue with the INNER JOIN. Shouldn't an INNER JOIN only show results where there is a match on the join column AND a NULL in the clause column?

Comment: It hard to say exactly without seeing your table structures but i will try and add an example to my answer that may help

Comment: I will add the full code, rather than a small section of it, this may help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the last part of the where condition.
You should use brackets.

```
`WHERE DPT.Department = 'Casualty'
   AND UPPER (C.ClientName) LIKE '%LIMITED%'
   AND CL.date > '31/12/2014'
   AND CL.Date IS NULL
   AND (TK.tkloc = 'loc1' OR TK.tkloc = 'loc2')`
```

or

```
`WHERE DPT.Department = 'Casualty'
   AND UPPER (C.ClientName) LIKE '%LIMITED%'
   AND CL.date > '31/12/2014'
   AND CL.Date IS NULL
   AND TK.tkloc IN ('loc1', 'loc2')`
```